# Own Framework won't pass variables

Tags: php, variables, foreach, naming-conventions

I'm doing a small PHP framework, I'm having issues passing the variables to the view...Here is what I do:

```
//  $vars is : array("foo1" => "bar1", "foo2" => "bar2")

if(is_array($vars))
        {
                    foreach ($vars as $key => $value)
                    {
                    $key = $value;
                    }
                }


        //add the view.
        include($path);
    }
```

So I'll like in my view access to $foo1 and $foo2, but they are NULL. How is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're doing is setting the value of the var `$key` to what it already is...

What I assume is your goal is getting the variables from the array into their own variable.

If that's the case then change

```
$key = $value;
```

Into

```
$$key = $value;
```

By using `$$` your setting new variables with the name of the `$key`

```
//  $vars is : array("foo1" => "bar1", "foo2" => "bar2")
foreach ($vars as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}

// results in:
// $foo1 = "bar1"
// $foo2 = "bar2"
```

Comment: was that! Thanks

Comment: @PeterCzask as mentioned by Mark Baker, you could also make use of PHP's [extract](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function which would let you skip the foreach loop, I assumed you did some extra checks in the loop though.